Should normalization be applied on interaction feature
I am working with interaction features in my machine learning model, where I create new features by multiplying a numeric variable with an encoded categorical feature. My question is:
Should normalization be applied to these interaction terms? If yes, so should it be applied before interaction features are created or after the interaction features are created ?
In my case, I am using Neural Networks and GBM (Gradient Boosting Machines), and I’m wondering whether normalization of interaction terms will affect model performance. By normalization, I mean scaling to a 0-1 range.
Challenges when creating interaction terms:

Numerical Features Normalized Before Interaction:

While this prevents the dominance of large numerical scales, it can
distort the relative magnitude of the interaction term, especially
when the categorical encoding carries meaningful differences (e.g.,
weighted target encoding). This approach may also introduce encoded
categorical bias, where the interaction term does not accurately
reflect the true relationship between the categorical and numerical
features.

Interaction Term Normalized After Creation:

This approach equalizes the scale of the interaction terms but can introduce a loss of interpretability for the interaction term and cause an uneven scale impact. In this case, the encoded categorical feature’s signal might get diluted, which could lead to potential bias in the model’s understanding of the relationships between the features.
How do you handle these challenges in your workflow?

Do you always normalize numerical features before creating
interactions?
How do you preserve interpretability when normalizing
interaction terms?
Any tips or best practices to balance scale, bias,
and interpretability in such cases?

For example, if I multiply a normalized numeric feature with a one-hot encoded categorical variable, does that change the original relationship between the numeric feature and the category, or does it still capture the intended interaction?
What did I try:
I have experimented with normalizing the numeric feature before creating the interaction term. Specifically, I normalized the numeric variable and then multiplied it with an encoded categorical feature. I also tried creating interaction features without normalizing the numeric variable first to compare the two approaches.
What was I expecting:
I was hoping to understand if normalizing the numeric feature before creating the interaction term would affect the model's ability to capture the intended relationships between the numeric and categorical features. I was also curious whether the meaning of the interaction term would be preserved or distorted due to the normalization of the numeric feature. I expected to learn whether normalization would cause the interaction term to lose its original scale and significance or if it would be beneficial for model convergence and performance.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Not all machine learning models require normalization, and some that do also provide ways to deal with interactions. Please edit the question to say more about the type of machine learning that you are engaged in. Also, "normalization" can take on several different meanings (scaling to 0 mean and unit standard deviation; restricting values to [0,1],...), so please specify what you mean by that word. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

At least for gradient boosted trees, there is no need either to standardize or to pre-define interaction terms (except if there are numerical problems due to measurement scales of variables). At each node a cutoff for a continuous predictor is chosen, so the scale itself doesn't matter. Allowing sufficient tree depth effectively lets the model discover interactions that you might not have suspected. You won't necessarily know what the discovered interaction end up being, although two-variable partial-dependence plots can help identify them and predictions from the model will certainly incorporate them. See, for example, Chapter 10 of The Elements of Statistical Learning (ESL) by Hastie et al.
I have no experience with fitting neural networks. I note that Chapter 11 of ESL, "Neural Networks," recommends (in contrast to your restriction to the interval [0,1]):

At the outset it is best to standardize all inputs to have mean zero and standard deviation one. This ensures all inputs are treated equally in the regularization process, and allows one to choose a meaningful range for the random starting weights. (page 400)

An interaction term is just the product between the interacting predictors. An interaction term between such a standardized continuous predictor and a 0/1 dummy-coded categorical predictor will still have mean zero and standard deviation one for each level of the categorical predictor coded with 1. Thus the model will treat the categorical-continuous interaction on the same scale as any other standardized continuous predictor.
